# Spring Data JPA n + 1 query problem when using nativeQuery

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Consider two entities **Thread** and **User**. Each thread **belongs to** a user. There are two methods in `ThreadRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface ThreadRepository extends JpaRepository<Thread, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH, attributePaths = {"user"})
    Page<Thread> findAllByOrderByCreatedDateDesc(Pageable pageable);

    @Query(value = "SELECT T.*, U.* FROM THREAD T LEFT JOIN FRM_USER U ON U.id = T.USER",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(T.ID) FROM THREAD T",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Thread> findAllCustomMethod(Pageable pageable);
}
```

I can handle *n + 1 query problem* for method `findAllByOrderByCreatedDateDesc` using `@EntityGraph`.

My question is what is the best solution to fix that problem for `findAllCustomMethod` method which contains `nativeQuery`?

Comment: It's already Lazy, I have `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` for user relation inside thread. @asgar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN FRM_USER` is not used in this case, and Spring Data JPA will only map `T.*` fields to `Thread`, ignoring `U.*` fields.

Instead, it can cause duplcates!

The JPA implementation will then lazily select User instances, causing the N+1 problem.

You can't use a Projection as "class-based projections do not work with native queries AT ALL".

In this precise case, the nativeQuery has no benefit over a JPQL query where you could use LEFT JOIN FETCH to eagerly fetch User instances and avoid N+1.
I guess you used this as an example.

Spring Data won't help here.

If you really need a SQL query, you can use SqlResultSetMapping.
See https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-sqlresultsetmapping/

When using SQL queries (aka. native queries), you can benefit from Spring's `JdbcTemplate.query` method with a custom `ResultSetExtractor` that will build your Objects with a custom implementation.
Implementing the solution for this precise case with `ResultSetExtractor` is pretty straightforward, but the pagination part will be quite verbose.

```java
public class ThreadJdbcRepository {

    private static final String QUERY = """
        SELECT t.*, u.*
        FROM thread t
        LEFT JOIN frm_user u ON u.id = t.user
        """;

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public ThreadJdbcRepository (JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public Collection<Thread> findAllCustomMethod() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(QUERY, rs -> {
            Map<Long, Thread> idToThread = new HashMap<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Thread thread;
                Long id = rs.getLong("id");
                thread = idToThread.computeIfAbsent(id, k ->
                    new Thread()
                    // build thread...
                );
                User user = new User();
                // build user...
                thread.addUser(user);
            }
            return idToThread.values();
        });
    }
}
```